# Update order to add attribute in Shopware

Tags: shopware

Hi,

I'm trying to update an order to add content to an attribute depending on user's selection. It is working so far but the attribute value is saved in the 'preorder' row which I don't know how to relate to the actual order row in the database:

[Database rows screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rz2nc.jpg)

Once the user clicks on the order now button it saves my value using the order id but this id it's not the final one, so when the order is confirmed a new row is inserted but they have nothing in common. Maybe I'm subscribed to the wrong event? At the moment I'm using **Enlight_Controller_Action_Frontend_Checkout_Finish** but the order seems to be not created at this stage, any other idea on how can I add information to an order?

Thank you

UPDATE:

Here's an answer from shopware forum which helped to find a workaround:

There are some more events you can use. If you take a look into the engine/Shopware/Core/sOrder.php file, there is a method called sSaveOrder() which will be called when saving an order.

When the method is executed, there are some events dispatched which may be useful for your use-case. For example:

```
Shopware_Modules_Order_SaveOrder_FilterParams
Shopware_Modules_Order_SaveOrder_FilterAttributes
Shopware_Modules_Order_SaveOrder_FilterDetailAttributes
Shopware_Modules_Order_SaveOrder_ProcessDetails
```

They will be dispatched in order I've listed them.

Answer (score 0):

Subscribe to **Enlight_Controller_Action_PostDispatch_Frontend_Checkout** event. On this event, check the action you wanted (ajaxCart / cart / confirm) and update your values to **s_order_basket_attributes**.
Those values would be available in final order row at s_order_attributes.

Comment: thank you. Finally I followed the recommendation from an answer in shopware forum and now I'm using a different event. Just updated my question with that information